# How do I manipulate binary digits in Data or NSData object using Swift in an iOS Xcode project or an Xcode Playground?

Tags: ios, swift, binary, boolean, nsdata

I am using Swift in an iOS Xcode project. I would like to use the Data or NSData object in the Apple Foundation and UIKit Frameworks to manipulate binary data so that each binary digit represents a boolean value -- 0 being false, and 1 being true.

How would I do that?

I would save the Data object in CloudKit as a field of type Bytes.

If there is an easier or more practical way for me to use boolean values that takes less memory and is more efficient, please suggest it to me.

I seem to recall there was a way to format numbers to a binary expression. That would help me accomplish my objective.

Comment: Every digit? Or every bit? Because that's even using less memory to use a bit for a boolean than a "hex digit" if I understood correctly which is a Byte.

Comment: @Larme Yes. That's what I'm trying to learn how to do.

Comment: @Larme, `hex digit` would be *half* of byte

Comment: @Larme I thought we would need to use other than a hex digit.

Comment: Good point, half digit. Are looking for bitfields?

Comment: @Larme I don't know what to call what I'm looking for. I'm open to any ideas. I'm not even sure what a bitfield is.